# Using Snowpack to transpile Web Components and package dependencies

Tags: django, lit-element, snowpack

I am using Django to build a SSR website and using Django to serve static files. I also built some Web Components using lit-element and Typescript. I would like to avoid the complexity of Webpack and use Snowpack instead. Components are stored at `/static/js/components`.

To use the components, I need to (1) transpile them to Javascript, (2) make available their dependencies (e.g. `lit-element`) and (3) move the transpired files as well as the `_snowpack` folder to Django's `/static/` folder.

Using just `snowpack build` does both but creates a `build` folder with a complete copy of the application. It is my understanding that [buildOptions.out](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/configuration#buildoptions.out) only moves the output folder (thereby overwriting `static/` altogether if `buildOptions.clean===true`). I guess it would be possible to script the copying of the necessary files and delete the rest of the `build` folder immediately, but that strikes me as quite inelegant.

Is there a configuration to only create `_snowpack` and the transpiled files to a specific directory?

Answer (score -1):

The [Django staticfiles module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/) supports having multiple directories for static files, and making them all available under the same /static/ URL.
That way, you won't have to copy those different type of assets into the same folder before being able to serve them with Django.